# calculate mean and standard deviation per row in array 2 dimensional

Tags: java, arrays

I have 2 dimensional array, I need too calculate mean and standard deviation per row and store it in the proper place. I have write the code but it still give me the wrong result, not giving the correct answer of the intended value. could anyone help me, perhaps my code is just wrong but i dont know how to correct it. Here's the array

[image]

And here's the code itself:

```
public void analyze(String[][] arr) {
   double res = 0.0;
   double avg = 0;
   double variance = 0;
   double SD;
   double Q = 0;
   int index = 0;

   for (int i = 1; i < (arr.length); i++) {
      for (int j = 1; j < (arr[i].length); j++) {
         res = res + Integer.parseInt(arr[i][j]);
      }

      avg = res / (arr[i].length - 1);

      System.out.print("arr[i].length:  " + arr[i].length + "\t");
      System.out.println("Average is " + avg);
      /*
      double v = Q + (arr.length - avg) * (arr.length - avg);
      variance = Q / (arr.length - 1);
      SD = Math.sqrt(variance);
      System.out.println("average is " + avg);
      System.out.println("SD");

      double nums[] = { 1.0, 2.3, 3.4, 4.5, 40.5 };
      double result = 0.0;
      for (i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
         result = result + nums[i];
      }
      System.out.println("Average is =" + result / nums.length);
      */
   }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You start both of your `for` loops on `1`. Arrays are zero indexed in Java. This causes you to miss the first row completely and the first column in each following row.

Change

```
    for(int i=1; i<(arr.length);i++){
        for(int j=1;j<(arr[i].length);j++){
        res = res+Integer.parseInt(arr[i][j]);
    }
```

to

```
    for(int i=0; i<(arr.length);i++){
        for(int j=0;j<(arr[i].length);j++){
        res = res+Integer.parseInt(arr[i][j]);
    }
```

Comment: Actually I start the loops with 1 since I will not count the first column and the first row because it is string value, not integer. by the code shown above, the result is only correct at the first row of array, the rest is just incorrect. looking through the help, thank you

Comment: O.K. - especially now that you have described the problem better, it's clear that @Perception found at least one bug - you need to reset res to 0.0.  Also, just "looking to the future", I'd suggest you use Double.parseDouble().  No harm in the current problem, and that way you can handle doubles in the future.

Comment: Mates, thank you for the help, I am successfully count it with correct output :)

Answer (score 1):

Your missing a calculation for `Q`. And you need to reset your calculation variables between each iteration of your outer loop.